# javascript behaviour - function expression vs function declaration - difference

Tags: javascript

Why no **reference** is created for function `f`

```js
if ( function f() { } ) {
    console.log( typeof f );
}
// result: undefined
```

Whereas **assigning/setting** variable works fine inside `if(  )`

```js
if ( f = 'assigned' ) {
     console.log( typeof f );
}
// result: string
```

I need to know that whats going on in the first case as the second case is working as expected

Can anybody explain, please?

Comment: https://kangax.github.io/nfe/

Comment: Need to see more code. What is function f?

Comment: @KyleJ. All code is there. Function `f` is `function f() {  }`

Comment: it looks like the function is not hoistable and vanishes.

Comment: For the same reason `f` is undefined when using `var g = function f () {}`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname/338053

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have put `function f() { }` in expression context, it is a *named function expression* and not a *function declaration*.

That means that while it creates a function, and that function has the name `f`, it creates the variable with the name `f` *in the scope of the function (itself)* and not *in the scope in which the function is created*.

```
// Global scope
function a() {
// a is a function declaration and creates a variable called a to which the function is assigned in the scope (global) that the declaration appears in
    function b() {
    // b is a function declaration and creates a variable called a to which the function is assigned in the scope (function a) that the declaration appears in
    }
    var c = function d() {
    // c is a variable in the scope of the function b. The function d is assigned to it explicitly
    // d is a function expression and creates a variable called d to which the function is assigned in the scope (function d) of itself

    };
}
```

Comment: @NinaScholz — Each function defines its own scope (and there is also the global scope). Named function expressions create a variable with the same name as the function inside themselves, which is useful for creating recursive functions. (In ES6 scope gets more complicated with the addition of block level scope to the language, but that's irrelevent here as only function scope is involved).

Comment: no, i mean the outside scope of the function. (the expression nature of the function, where it looks like an expression is a very good explanation.)

Comment: Maybe you should add a reference that explains the difference between function expressions and function declaration.

Comment: @NinaScholz — There are (potentially) lots of scopes that are outside the function. It isn't available in any of them though.